# Is File New Window in Browser is equivalent to window.open()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, window.open, new-window

Is File New Window in Browser is equivalent to window.open()?

In a scenario, a site has two frames(with frameset, not iframes), top frame shows the menu and second frame shows the any respective page of the menu. In the page,trying to open a report in a new window by window.open(url,...). By opening new window, expectation is that the report gets loaded seperately, so that we can navigate away from the page around the site for other pages. But any click on top frame requests are getting queued up, until the child window loads completely.

briefly, ***any opened window loading is queuing up parent window navigation request*** (observe in Fiddler)? How can we achieve parent window navigation does not effect child window loading?

(I tried opening in an iframe and load with ajax, async =true but not helpful :( 
thanks
HydTechie

Comment: window.open doesn't behave like that (http://jsfiddle.net/yBLPy/), show us the relevant piece of script for further considerations